# Adding Swagger to Spring MVC project (Error creating bean)

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, swagger, swagger-ui

this is a very simple thing usually but I have sat with it for long and have tried multiple configurations and git repositories but can't get it to work.

The errors I receive looks like this:

> SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener
>   instance of class
>   org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name
>   'com.mangofactory.swagger.configuration.SpringSwaggerConfig#0':
>   Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not
>   autowire field: private com.mangofactory.swagger.models.ModelProvider
>   com.mangofactory.swagger.configuration.SpringSwaggerConfig.modelProvider;
>   nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:292)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1185)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:304)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:300)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:195)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:703)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:760)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:403)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106)
>     at

This error is somehow connected, but don't know why it doesn't work. Have tried MVN:clean and updated but it doesn't work.

My setup looks like this:

**src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/config/rest-services-config.xml:**

```
<mvc:default-servlet-handler/>

<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:config/swagger.properties"/>

<!-- creates a controller at /api-docs from this uri, which serves swagger's raw documentation in JSON format. -->
<bean class="com.mangofactory.swagger.configuration.SpringSwaggerConfig" />
```

**src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/Web xml:**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
  <display-name>Test Swagger</display-name>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
            /WEB-INF/config/rest-services-config.xml
        </param-value>
  </context-param>
 <listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
  </listener>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>restservices</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
      <param-value></param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>restservices</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>




</web-app>
```

**pom.xml**

```
    <dependency>
<groupId>com.mangofactory</groupId>
<artifactId>swagger-springmvc</artifactId>
<version>0.9.4</version>
```

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
        <version>${jackson.mapper.version}</version>
    </dependency>

<repositories>
    <repository>
      <id>jcenter-release</id>
      <name>jcenter</name>
      <url>http://oss.jfrog.org/artifactory/oss-release-local/</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

And have added the required libraries in project.
Why can't I use swagger?
I also want to add swagger-ui afterwards, will that work?

Thanks in forehand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me it seems that you are missing Jackson dependency in your POM:

```
is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper
```

Comment: I have this, sorry for not adding it. I will edit now..   <dependency>
   <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
   <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
   <version>${jackson.mapper.version}</version>
  </dependency>

Answer (score 0):

I succesfully managed to fix this, but another error came up which is more strange.
However this is the solution:
I added this to my pom.xml file:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: You should have accepted the other answer as it pointed out the problem correctly and suggested the solution.